# Preventing class data inheritance

Tags: php, oop, class, class-design

I have a database abstraction layer that starts with a base class like so:

```
class DB {
  function DB() {
    $this->host = "xxx";
    $this->db = "xxx";
    $this->user = "xx";
    $this->pass = "xx";
    $this->dbh = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass);
    mysql_select_db($this->db);
    // etc
  }
}

class DBI extends DB {
  // etc
}
```

Now I would like for the child classes to inherit the database handle but not the credentials. I tried (in the DBI class):

```
    function DBI (){ 
        $this->host ='';
        $this->db ='';
        $this->user ='';
        $this->pass ='';
    }
```

But that kills the handle; not sure why.  Also tried:

```
class DBI extends DB {
    var $host ='';
    var $db ='';
    var $user ='';
    var $pass ='';
}
```

to no effect.

So I am wondering if what I ought to do is just move the database connection out of the class altoghether?  Just start the class file with a connection and leave it at that?

Opinions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the simplest approach is just to move the connection out of the classes. If I start off the class file with the connection then the handle is available to all the classes without making $dbh a class attribute.

Answer (score 3):

Then don't make them member variables

```
<?php
class DB
{
  var $dbh;

  function DB()
  {
    $this->dbh = mysql_connect( "xxx", "xxx", "xx" );
    mysql_select_db( "xx", $this->dbh );
    // etc
  }
}

class DBI extends DB {
  // etc
}
```

or switch to PHP5 and make them private

```
<?php
class DB
{
  private
      $host = "xxx"
    , $db   = "xxx"
    , $user = "xx"
    , $pass = "xx"
  ;

  protected $dbh;

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->dbh = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass);
    mysql_select_db( $this->db, $this->dbh );
    // etc
  }
}

class DBI extends DB {
  // etc
}
```

and I should not that you need to remember you pass your connection handle to functions like [mysql_select_db()](http://us.php.net/mysql_select_db) to stay multi-connection safe.

### EDIT!

> But that kills the handle; not sure why.

Because PHP doesn't cascade constructors (the parent class' constructor isn't implicitly called).  That means `DB::DB()` isn't automatically called when you create an instance of `DBI`. So you have to do that explicitly.  So I guess this is another option but I don't really like it

```
class DBI extends DB
{
  function DBI()
  {
    // Call the parent constructor
    parent::DB();

    // Now empty these member variables
    $this->host = '';
    $this->db   = '';
    $this->user = '';
    $this->pass = '';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not pass the database settings in via the constructor:

```
function DB($host, $db, $user, $pass) {
    $this->host = $host;
    $this->db = $db;
    $this->user = $user;
    $this->pass = $pass;
    $this->dbh = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass);
    mysql_select_db($this->db);
}
```

Then you can do

```
function DBI() {
    parent::DB('xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx');
}
```

(In both PHP4 and PHP5, the parent constructor will not be called implicitly. This is why your handle is "killed" in your `DBI` subclass; it never gets initialized. What you *really* need is to switch to PHP5, though :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want a child class to inherit a property, you can declare it as private.  This only works for PHP 5:

```
class DB {

  private $host = "xxx";
  private $db = "xxx";
  private $user = "xx";
  private $pass = "xx";

  function DB() {
    $this->dbh = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass);
    mysql_select_db($this->db);
    // etc
  }
}
```

However, I wouldn't recommend this approach.  Database settings are better off stored in a configuration file.  In this way, it's easier to re-use your code between applications.

It's still very common to make a configuration variable be an array inside a file named `config.php`, and then use that array as a global in functions that require it.  However, it's also a good idea to stay away from globals when possible.  There are some good designs of how to manage a configuration class out there, for instance [Zend_Config](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.config.html).  You can get some good ideas from how they've done it.

Comment: When I do it that way and dump a child object I still get the values, just flagged as private:

Incentive Object
(
    [table] => membership_incentivesV2
    [changedVals] => Array
        (
        )

    [connectionError] => 
    [host:private] => xxx
    [db:private] => xxx
    [user:private] => xxx
    [pass:private] => xxx
    [dbh] => Resource id #4
)

Comment: Don't confuse the output of var_dump with actual class-member visibility.  Yes, the data is there, but instances of `DBI` cannot read variables declared as private in `DB`